# Sum Dplyr Function inside a classical R Function (n() work but not sum!)

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I've read every available SOF threads on this topic. Ain't able to fix my problem. I want to build a function with dataset name, variable name and group name as parameters. I want to use dplyr function summarize, sum and n(). It seems to be all good when I put only n(). But everything fails when I want to compute the sum inside each group.

Here is my function :

```
library(MASS)
library(ISLR)

dplyrfun <- function(dataframe, variable1,variable2){
  dataframe %>% 
    group_by_(variable1) %>% 
    summarise_(
      freq = ~n(),
      freq_weighted = ~sum(variable2)
    )
}
```

So when i execute this command :

```
dplyrfun(Boston, ~rad,~age)
```

I got this error message :

```
Error in sum(~c(65.2, 9.9, 18.8, 32, 19.1, 24.8, 20.8, 31.9, 31.5, 28.4,  : 
  invalid 'type' (language) of argument
```

Comment: Because `sum(~age)` doesn't work. You need to use `interpolate()` or similar. See the NSE vignette

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As hadley points out, this is all in the [dplyr NSE vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html). Using `lazyeval::interp()`:

```
library(MASS)
library(ISLR)
library(dplyr)
library(lazyeval)

dplyrfun <- function(dataframe, variable1, variable2){
  dataframe %>% 
    group_by_(interp(~ var, var = as.name(variable1))) %>% 
    summarise_(
      freq = ~n(),
      freq_weighted = interp(~ sum(var), var = as.name(variable2))
    )
}
```

But you will need to put the column names in quotes:

```
dplyrfun(Boston, "rad", "age")
Source: local data frame [9 x 3]

  rad freq freq_weighted
1   1   20         900.5
2   2   24        1554.5
3   3   38        1873.8
4   4  110        6692.6
5   5  115        7960.7
6   6   26        1563.7
7   7   17         682.4
8   8   24        1616.4
9  24  132       11854.3
```

And just to check:

```
identical(
  dplyrfun(Boston, "rad", "age"),
  Boston %>%
    group_by_(~ rad) %>%
    summarise_(
      freq = ~n(),
      freq_weighted = ~ sum(age)
    )
)

[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Awsome!! You made my day, I really mean it!! I've struggled so long with this shit! Yeah I understood it lies with NSE principles but didn't get it!